# The goal is to obtain the minimum number of subsets of size s from a set of items of size a, so that pair of items should appear in exactly n subsets

Tags: algorithms, combinatorial-designs

I am not a mathematician, I hope the question is sufficiently clear and has a solution.

The use case is the design of an online experiment.

- Parameter `a` is typically between 10 and 1000.
- Parameter `s` is typically between 3 and 6.
- Parameter `n` is typically between 1 and 20.

If a formal solution does not exist or is very computationally intensive, an algorithmic solution that would give an approximate, faster answer would be great as well (list of subsets where *almost* all pairs of items appear in n subsets).

Comment: Thank you. Indeed! I had another constraint to the problem but ommited it, thinking I need to make the problem as simple as possible. But as you point out, it just makes the question pointless. Let me edit the question.

Comment: If you didn't really mean "list **all** the subsets of size $s$" but just want a collection of $s$-element subsets of an $a$-element set such that each $2$-element set is covered by $n$ members of the collection, then you probably want to read about [block designs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_design).

Comment: Balanced Incomplete Block Design is indeed my use case. I have read the wikipedia article. I was posting here to get further explanations on how to implement it.

Comment: You want a family $F$ of $s$-sized subsets of an $a$-sized set $A$ such that **every** pair if elements of $A$ is contained in **exactly** $n$ members of $F$. It doesn't make sense to ask for the **minimum** size of such a family $F$. Such a family may or may not exist, but if it exists it must have **exactly** $\frac{na(a-1)}{s(s-1}$ members. Now, if you were to say that each pair of elements of $A$ must be contained in **at least** $n$ members of $F$, then asking for the minimum size of $F$ is a well-considered set covering problem.